# Custom controls not visible in the View

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

Below is my code I used to create a custom UITextField in code behind.

`UITextField usernameField;`

`usernameField = new UITextField`
`{`
`Placeholder = "Enter your username",`
`BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect,`
`Frame = new RectangleF(10, 32, 50, 30)`
`};`

`View.AddSubview(usernameField);`

But when I run my app, I dont see this anywhere. Not only this control but all the controls that I create in code behind. 
If I drag the controls from toolbox onto my View it's working very fine.
What might be the cause?

Comment: can you post your full view?. are you doing this in your ViewDidLoad?

Comment: Yes, I'm doing this in ViewDidLoad

Comment: I think you're going to have to give more info for someone to help you. What does the code in your controller look like? What do you have defined in the storyboard? What does a screenshot of the app look like?

Comment: I really dont think the need of app's screenshot and all. But I can say what I've done in the storyboard.
1. I created a new viewcontroller (ViewController1) in the storyboard and it placed no controls.
2. I tried to add a new control through code behind and the code I tried is above.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Container View is not transparent so Alpha = 1 and set background colors for appropriate controlls. Because by default its set to Clear
You can use this method to easly set background and rounded corners like in older versions of iOS
    `public static void MakeViewRounded(UIView view,float cornerRadius, MonoTouch.CoreGraphics.CGColor backgroundColor)
    {
        view.Layer.CornerRadius = cornerRadius;
        view.Layer.BackgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    }`

Also make sure that you adding your custom controll to ViewController/View